# Get project directory for custom task SSIS

Tags: c#, ssis, directory, task

I am building a custom SSIS task. In the task, I run some scripts. These are located in the project/ in a subfolder scripts/.

Now the problem is when I debug my task from BIDS:

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

returns: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 9.0\Common7`

But if I run/debug from visual studio (with DTExec) I get:

```
C:\Users\nwadike\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BloombergRequest\BloombergRequest\bin
```

Now if I use: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location`,
I get: `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\BloombergRequest\versionNum\BBG.dll` whether I debug from SSIS or Visual studio...

**Basically I am looking for how to get a relative path to project\scripts\**.... How is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way within SSIS to get a relative path to a particular folder in a Visual Studio project - which makes sense, since the whole Visual Studio project normally doesn't get deployed with the package. And, as you noted, the concept of the "current directory" doesn't help, as it's based on where the executable is run from, not where the source code lives.

However, there's a (sort-of) straightforward workaround.

1. Add a property to your custom task for the **absolute** path to the scripts folder.
2. In the SSIS package using the custom task, set that property to the value of a package variable, and configure the package to get that variable from a configuration file (.dtsconfig)
3. Either:

   - In your Visual Studio solution, add another C# DLL project. It doesn't need to have any code in it. Instead, in the project's Build Events property page, call a script that generates the .dtsconfig file in step 2 and pass the macro `$(SolutionDir)/project/scripts` as an argument; **or**
   - Manually set the configuration value to the absolute path to your scripts folder

Answer (score -1):

use:

```
Environment.CurrentDirectory
```

Comment: Unfortunately when I debug from BIDS this returns:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 9.0\Common7\IDE`...
And from VS:
`C:\Users\nwadike\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\BloombergRequest\BloombergRequest\bin\Debug`...